# using a struct vs a reference variable in a game loop

Tags: c#, loops, variables, struct, game-development

I'm getting my feet wet with Mono game. Mostly because I think its a more interesting way to improve my coding skills.

My question is, am I better off using a referenced variable in the game loop's update method, or a light weight struct?(Will only be initialized with 2 ints)

```
var GameObject GObject = new GameObject(); 
int Move=1;
void update  
{
    if(key.left)
   GObject.Location.x -= Move;
}
```

or instead doing

```
 void update  
{
    if(key.left)
   GObject.Location = new Vector2(updatedX,Y);
}
```

Since Vector2s are structs, I cannot change the x value inside the object's vector unless I make a new one. I read Microsoft's example on when a struct would be preferred, but I'm not sure if it applies the same way.

I imagine there are tools in mono that are meant to do this for me, but I'd still like to know if having many iterations a second changes things.

Finally, I know I can declare the Vector in the Game class, but I was trying to have the Game objects manage their own locations.

Comment: You're not liable to see performance impact from such a lightweight actor until you have hundreds of thousands, if not millions of them. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Also, in the future you'll probably get better game development oriented answers at the gamedev stack exchange! https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: @SomeGuy Incorrect.This was discussed verbatim in all XNA forums; guidelines and articles and the consensus is that you should use `struct`s where ever possible so as to avoid deadly pauses from the GC.  Additionally, you should avoid `foreach` because it creates another object that will impact GC.  By the way, Monogame is a fork of XNA and suffers the same problems. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2007/07/02/twin-paths-to-garbage-collector-nirvana/

Comment: @MickyD Oh cool, I stand corrected. Surely what you have here is a satisfactory answer, though?

Comment: @SomeGuy also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/etayrien/2007/03/16/foreach-garbage-and-the-clr-profiler/.  oh, didnt think of that, I shall add below thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

summary of above comment.

---

**TL; DR:** for high performance apps like games, you should try to use `struct`s wherever possible, particularly for short lived situations as in a loop.

This was discussed verbatim in all XNA forums; guidelines and articles and the consensus is that you should use `struct`s where ever possible so as to avoid **deadly pauses** from the GC which can hurt games. Additionally, you should generally **avoid** `foreach` because it creates another object that will impact GC due to boxing I believe.  The problem was particularly bad back in the day for c# games written for the XBox 360 or c# games pre .NET 4.

By the way, Monogame is a fork of XNA and suffers the same problems

In typical desktop/web development, go ahead and use reference types because the GC is much more efficient and doesn't suspend the entire app whilst GC is underway.

- .NET 4+ on Windows desktop has background GC
- .NET 4.5+ on Windows Server has background GC

### Tell me more

- [Shawn Hargreaves Blog
  Twin paths to garbage collector nirvana](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2007/07/02/twin-paths-to-garbage-collector-nirvana/)
- [Foreach, Garbage, and the CLR Profiler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/etayrien/2007/03/16/foreach-garbage-and-the-clr-profiler/)

Comment: I really appreciate this answer. After reading the article, the reason I was thinking was completely different than the answer. I'm glad I asked.

Comment: @Rye you are quite welcome good sir.  Shawn Hargreaves (MSFT) blog is really good.  Also check out [this old forum](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/), might not be active anymore though.  Don't forget to accept the answer if you think it is groovy.  Helps to feed the wife and kids.  Oh wait I don't have any ;)